# Re-query mysql on .change <select>

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, highcharts

The idea:

You enter the page with a (high-)chart in it displaying a series for current year fetched from mysql - Works fine, no problem.

Selection from dropdown should update the query to show the year selected from dropdown.
The dropdown:

```
<select id="set_data">
<?php 
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT year FROM chartdata ORDER BY year DESC";
    $r = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
        echo '<option value="'.$row['year'].'">'.$row['year'].'</option>';
    }
?>
</select>
```

jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#set_data').change(function() {
    $('.data_set').load('fetch_charts/highchart_ad.php?id='+this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);
});
</script>
```

So basically what i'm doing is loading a new set of highchart script on the same content - that doesn't give me much... obviously, but I have totally stopped

Please help

- UPDATE -
Basicly what i'm looking for:
1. Entering the the page = 2014 visible... 
2. Select 2013 from dropdown and chart updates with 2013 data.

Comment: The code looks reasonable. What's not working?

Comment: It is, but when i'm entering the page with the chart displayed with current year (SELECT year FROM TB WHERE year = date("Y")... echo values into highchart series script) the dropdown above loads a new set of highchart scripts.. Double trouble...

Comment: So have the highchart scripts not be loaded via `fetch_charts/highchart_ad.php`.

Comment: ok, but how do you throw the new selected value from dropdown into "old"/first query ("re-query")??

Comment: 1. Entering the the page = 2014 visible... 2.Select 2013 from dropdown and chart updates with 2013 displayed. **Original question updated..**

Comment: anyone? Can't sort it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some trying and failing - my own result on the problem above..

(thought i could be nice to share, also to close this post)

```
<form action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>' method='post'>
    <select name="set_year" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <?php 
        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT year FROM chartdata ORDER BY year DESC";
        $r = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
            echo '<option value="'.$row['year'].'">'.$row['year'].'</option>';
        }
    ?>
    </select>
</form>

<?php
    $year = date('Y');
    $set_year = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['set_year']);

    if(empty($set_year)){
        $A = "SELECT * FROM chartdata WHERE year = $year";
    }
    else{
        $A = "SELECT * FROM chartdata WHERE year = $set_year";
    }

    $da = mysqli_query($con, $A);
    while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($da)){
        $dataset[]= $result['data'];
        //getting the data and putting them into highchart series -> data.
    }
?>

    <script>
        //highchart script
        //...

        series: [{
            data: [<?php echo join($dataset, ',')?>]
        }]  
    </script>
```

Above works fine.
Any other solutions/ comments are welcome =)